# How to test Redux async action with redux-axios-middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

My Redux store is configured with redux-thunk and redux-axios-middleware for fetching data with axios HTTP clients.

I have an action that works perfectly in development but I'm failing to test it  with jest. Here is the action :

```
export const subscribeTrial = trialingDuration => dispatch => {
  const message = `You're now Premium✨ for ${trialingDuration} days!`;

  return dispatch({
    type: SUBSCRIBE_TRIAL,
    payload: {
      request: {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/subscriptions/trial',
      },
    },
  }).then(({ type }) => {
    if (type === SUBSCRIBE_TRIAL_SUCCESS) {
      dispatch(
        showHeadMessage(message, { type: 'info', discardTimeout: 5000 }),
      );
    }
  });
};
```

Here is my current test that fails :

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore();

beforeEach(() => {
  store.clearActions();
});

it('can start trial', () => {
  const expectedAction = {
    type: SUBSCRIBE_TRIAL,
    payload: {
      request: {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/subscriptions/trial',
      },
    },
  };

  store.dispatch(subscribeTrial());

  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([expectedAction]);
});
```

Jest keeps pointing at the `.then()` and raising the following error :

```
TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong ? Can't figure it out.

Comment: Where/how are you using axios?

Comment: I use redux-axios-middleware for fetching data with axios HTTP client

Comment: You need to add the middleware that actually does the request to the mocked store. Or you could create a middleware that somehow fakes this behaviour. Otherwise the result of dispatch call is a POJO not a Promise.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you that is the solution and I found a way to do it in the lib's issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @YuryTarabanko 's comment :

> add the middleware that actually does the request to the mocked store

I fixed the test by adding my axios client and middleware to the store :

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';

import axiosClients from '../../services/http_clients';

const middlewares = [thunk, multiClientMiddleware(axiosClients)];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

it('can start trial', () => {
  const store = mockStore({
    user: { email: 'user@example.com', authenticationToken: '123456' },
  });

  const expectedAction = {
    type: SUBSCRIBE_TRIAL,
    payload: {
      request: {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/subscriptions/trial',
      },
    },
  };

  store.dispatch(subscribeTrial());
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([expectedAction]);
});
```